# Js array to array of strings with different types

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I'm trying to have a form that allows to send json from a form.

One of my input should be an array of the form `["1","2","3"]` or `["foo","bar"]`
I'm having an issue with my user passing the array in a SINGLE field from the form.

I would like my user to be able to input(html) `[1,2,3]` and have it converted to  `["1","2","3"]` or `[foo,bar]` and have to converted to ["foo","bar"].

json.Stringify obviously doesn't work in that case.

I'm having difficulties doing that as **i do not know in advance that the input field will be an array or a string or a number.**

I'm currently storing the content of my form in an object in my controller but obviously when inputing [1,2,3] i get "[1,2,3]" and when inputing `["1","2","3"]` that data passed i get `[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]`

Is there a tool/function to does that automatically ?

Note: 
-the input of 1 field NEEDS to be an array is i don't know in advance the type of the array nor the number of items it will have.
- I'm using angular but that's more of a js problem i believe.

Comment: Solving this seems as simple as detecting whether the string begins and ends with a bracket, then splitting the string by commas, then outputting the resulting string array with quotes.

Comment: going to try something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this `cast` function:

```js
function cast(s) {
    if (s.match(/^\s*\[.*\]\s*$/)) { // array notation
        return s.trim().replace(/^\[|\]$/g, '').split(',').map(cast);
    }
    // remove wrapping quotes if present
    return s.trim().replace(/^'(.*)'$|^"(.*)"$/g, '$1$2');
}
// I/O for demo
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function () {
    var s = cast(this.value);
    document.querySelector('span').textContent = JSON.stringify(s);
});
```

```html
Your input: <input><br>
Output JSON: <span></span>
```

Note that the user can optionally type the quotes. Whether they do so or not, the result will be the same. It works to same for singular values: if quotes are wrapped around the input, they give the same string as without.

Comment: What should be the input in your example to get ["1","2","3"] as output ? seems like i don't quite get it

Comment: I see, you never want to get the number type. I updated my answer -- it makes it simpler in fact.

Comment: perfect! Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map` function:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr = arr.map(function(el){return el.toString()});
//The output array will be ["1","2","3"]
```

and for [foo, bar] I think you can't convert it because it's a variable and you will get it's value instead of it's name.

i wish that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of user inputting `[1,2,3]`, notify user to input `1,2,3` or `foo,bar`.

```js
let arr = [];
for (let input of document.querySelectorAll("form input")) {
  arr.push(input.value.split(","));
}
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(arr[0])
  , JSON.stringify(arr[1])
)
```

```html
<form>
  <label>input number,number,number:</label>
  <input placeholder="input number,number,number" value="1,2,3"/>
  <br>
  <label>input word,word,word:</label>
  <input placeholder="input word,word,word" value="foo, bar"/>
</form>
```